# Javascript fade in doesn't visibly animate

Tags: javascript, fadein, fade

So I've created the following function to fade elements in and passed in a div that I want to fade in which in this case is an image gallery popup that I want to show when a user clicks an image thumbnail on my site. I'm also passing in a speed value (iSpeed) which the timeout uses for it's time value. In this case I'm using 25 (25ms).

I've stepped through this function whilst doing so it appears to be functioning as expected. If the current opacity is less than 1, then it is incremented and it will recall itself after the timeout until the opacity reaches 1. When it reaches one it stops fading and returns.

So after stepping through it, I take off my breakpoints and try to see it in action but for some reason my gallery instantly appears without any sense of fading.

```
var Effects = new function () {

    this.Fading = false;

    this.FadeIn = function (oElement, iSpeed) {

        //set opacity to zero if we haven't started fading yet.
        if (this.Fading == false) {
            oElement.style.opacity = 0;
        }

        //if we've reached or passed max opacity, stop fading
        if (oElement.style.opacity >= 1) {
            oElement.style.opacity = 1;
            this.Fading = false;
            return;
        }
        //otherwise, fade
        else {
            this.Fading = true;
            var iCurrentOpacity = parseFloat(oElement.style.opacity);
            oElement.style.opacity = iCurrentOpacity + 0.1;
            setTimeout(Effects.FadeIn(oElement, iSpeed), iSpeed);
        }

    }

}
```

Here's where I'm setting up the gallery.

```
this.Show = function (sPage, iImagesToDisplay, oSelectedImage) {

        //create and show overlay
        var oOverlay = document.createElement('div');
        oOverlay.id = 'divOverlay';
        document.body.appendChild(oOverlay);

        //create and show gallery box
        var oGallery = document.createElement('div');
        oGallery.id = 'divGallery';
        oGallery.style.opacity = 0;
        document.body.appendChild(oGallery);

        //set position of gallery box
        oGallery.style.top = (window.innerHeight / 2) - (oGallery.clientHeight / 2) + 'px';
        oGallery.style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (oGallery.clientWidth / 2) + 'px';

        //call content function
        ImageGallery.CreateContent(oGallery, sPage, iImagesToDisplay, oSelectedImage);

        //fade in gallery
        Effects.FadeIn(oGallery, 25);

    }
```

Could anyone help me out?

Also, I'm using IE10 and I've also tried Chrome, same result.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Any reason you're not going this with CSS and the `transition` property?

Comment: You say you're using 25ms. Show us the code.

Comment: Added gallery setup function that calls the fadein.

Comment: I must say this is a weird interface.  `this.Fading` is a property of your `Effects` namespace so you couldn't use Effects for multiple animations.  Further, you pass `iSpeed` as not the duration of the animation, but the step time value.  And, you only increment `0.1` opacity at a time which isn't very granular.  And, if you watch the opacity values (which are floats) you will see that they go to 0.79999, 0.89999, 0.999999, 1.0999999999 which probably isn't exactly what you want.  If would also prefer not to do `oElement.style.opacity >= 1` with a string in `oElement.style.opacity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
setTimeout(Effects.FadeIn(oElement, iSpeed), iSpeed);
```

**calls** `Effects.FadeIn` with the given arguments, and feeds its return value into `setTimeout`. This is exactly like `foo(bar())`, which **calls** `bar` immediately, and then feeds its return value into `foo`.

Since your `FadeIn` function doesn't return a function, that would be the problem.

Perhaps you meant:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    Effects.FadeIn(oElement, iSpeed);
}, iSpeed);
```

...although you'd be better off creating that function once and reusing it.

For instance, I think this does what you're looking for, but without recreating functions on each loop:

```
var Effects = new function () {

    this.FadeIn = function (oElement, iSpeed) {
        var fading = false;

        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            //set opacity to zero if we haven't started fading yet.
            if (fading == false) { // Consider `if (!this.Fading)`
                oElement.style.opacity = 0;
            }

            //if we've reached or passed max opacity, stop fading
            if (oElement.style.opacity >= 1) {
                oElement.style.opacity = 1;
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            //otherwise, fade
            else {
                fading = true;
                var iCurrentOpacity = parseFloat(oElement.style.opacity);
                oElement.style.opacity = iCurrentOpacity + 0.1;
            }
        }, iSpeed);
    };
};
```

Comment: Ahh yes. Damn, I feel silly now lol. Thank you very much. Changed to this and now have a nice fadein effect :D. Thank you very much!

Comment: @andyfurniss: :-) Glad that helped! I've also posted a (completely untested) suggestion for how to change it to avoid creating functions repeatedly.

Comment: Ahh yes, that does look better. I'll give that a go and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @andyfurniss: Each time we call `setTimeout(function() { /* ... */ }, iSpeed);`, we're creating a new function object. It's not a big thing, but there's no need to do it.

Comment: @andyfurniss: I just caught an error in the `setInterval` version, which I've fixed (and the fix addresses the issue of `this.Fading` being shared, which others have raised).

Comment: Great. I've just tried to do the same thing for a Fade Out function however I'm having the same problem that I had before - it's just disappearing. All I've done is copied the function (and renamed it) changed the 1's to 0's, the 0's to 1's and changed the + to a -. Oh, and the > to a <. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, after the FadeOut I was removing them from the page with `document.body.removeChild`. I took this out and it fades properly. So  the fade and the removeChild seem to be happening at the same time somehow even though the code to remove them is after the call to the FadeOut function.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments. After adding in some breakpoints I've discovered that when we call The FadeOut, it steps in successfully but then skips over the `setInterval` (presumably after 25ms?), then steps out and does the `removeChild` lines and then jumps back into the `setInterval` within the FadeOut. Seems pretty weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of problems. The one culpable for the element appearing immediately is that you call setTimeout not with a function but with the result of a function, because Effects.FadeIn will be executed immediately.

```
setTimeout(function(){Effects.FadeIn(oElement, iSpeed)}, iSpeed);
```

will probably act as you intend.

But seriously, you probably should not re-invent this wheel. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) will allow you to fade elements in and out easily and [CSS transitions](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/) allow you to achieve element fading with as much as adding or removing a CSS class.

Comment: I know this is true but I really don't like using jQuery and I'm aware of transitions. This is more of a personal exercise than doing it the easy way though.

Answer (score 1):

[T.J.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19717599/105570) and [MoMolog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19717623/105570) are both right about the bug: you're invoking the `Effects.FadeIn` function immediately before passing the result to `setTimeout`—which means that `Effects.FadeIn` calls itself synchronously again and again until the condition `oElement.style.opacity >= 1` is reached.

As you may or may not know, many UI updates that all take place within one turn of the event loop will be batched together on the next repaint (or something like that) so you won't see any sort of transition.

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MufzZ/) includes the suggested JS solution, as well as an alternate approach that I think you may find to be better: simply adding a CSS class with [the transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions). This will result in a smoother animation. Note that if you go this route, though, you may need to also include some vendor prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As part of my job, we have to support version of IE all the way back to 7 which is why I haven't used transitions for this. This project isn't for work but it keeps me in the habit of covering all browsers.